# How can I hide or remove the CKEditor "collapse toolbar" button?

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar

I've successfully set up CKEditor and it works well, but the collapse toolbar button (3) irks me:

[image: In the lower right-hand corner, there is a button with an upwards-facing arrow, circled with the label 3.]

Is there any way to hide or remove it? If so, how?

Comment: -1; how in the world is anyone supposed to figure out the question that was being asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from this [source](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/3960)

You can easily disable it in plugins/toolbar/plugin.js

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', 
 {
    toolbarCanCollapse : false
 }
);
```

or

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbarCanCollapse = false;
```